# is there a good practice to use a localization that is then complemented with String interpolation?

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I have a translation whose phrase is static but then it is complemented with a piece of information that varies according to the user. It would be something like this:
"**" The person resides in "+ (data that varies)**".

"The person resides in" would be the static text for Localization.

Data that varies would be the interpolation of a string.

I know there is **%d** for numbers in Localization, does this apply to a string? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the variable data doesn't depend on current locale you could just use the regular `%@` for string arguments. Let's say you have this line in the `.strings` file:

```
"stringKey" = "The person resides in %@";
```

And then you can localize it like this:

```
String(format: NSLocalizedString("stringKey", comment: ""), data)
```

You may want to wrap it into an extension:

```
extension String {
    func localized(_ arg: String) -> String {
        String(format: NSLocalizedString(self, comment: ""), arg)
    }
}
```

In order to keep your code cleaner:

```
"stringKey".localized(data)
```

Or just use the [R.swift](https://github.com/mac-cain13/R.swift) library which does it for yourself, so you would have it like this:

```
R.string.localizable.stringKey(data)
```